# what is the use of string::format. i am no getting it on internet as well

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2015

```
void updateList(void) {
    numCam = get_noofcameras_connected();
        if (numCam != 0) {
            CameraSelect->Text = ("Please select Camera");
            CameraSelect->Items->Add("ALL");

            for (int i = 1; i < numCam + 1; i++) {
                CameraSelect->Items->Add(string::format("Camera {0}", i));
            }
        }
        else {
            CameraSelect->Text = ("NO CAMERA CONNECTED");
        }

    }
```

it is giving the error string is ambiguous .

Comment: your code looks very sharpy to me... are you sure you are using c++ and not c#???

Comment: There is no `string::format`. There is `std::format` from C++20, but you won't get that to work in VS 2015.

Comment: Is this C++/CLI for .NET? If so you probably want String::Format

Answer (score 0):

for c# you can call `.Format`

here an example from the

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1)

```
Decimal pricePerOunce = 17.36m;
String s = String.Format("The current price is {0} per ounce.",
                         pricePerOunce);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: are you sure your project is written in c++??